# Selecting from cursor to end of line in VS Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Had to wipe my computer and reinstall VS Code. The command+shift+arrow shortcut works in other apps, but not in VS Code. My goal is to select all text from the cursor to the start or end of the line.

In Keyboard Shortcuts, the cursorEndSelect command looks like it has the correct keybinding, but it doesn't work in practice. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: that is word-end, use `shift+End`

Comment: @rioV8 Don't want to use `shift+End` (`fn+shift+right` in macOS I believe). I want to use `cmd+shift+right` like everywhere else on my mac. VS Code is the only place it doesn't work. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: you can remove a keybinding and set a new command to this keybinding, see doc page on keybinding

Comment: @rioV8 the keybinding is already correct in the image I attached, but the shortcut doesn't work...

Comment: find out if there is another command having the same keybinding. Use the GUI and type your shortcut while recording, see keybinding doc page

Comment: doesn't even recognize the left and right arrows after specifying "cmd+shift" in the keybinding window

Comment: Fixed it!.......by downloading Atom :)

Comment: Oops! Atom again !!